# RUN yum in Docker file not working, but yum it's working inside the container

Tags: docker, amazon-ami

I'm trying to build a container from amazonlinux (fedora based).

If I build the image and I enter into the container the yum command works normally.
However if I put the yum command inside the Dockerfile, it doesn't. It seems that fails to contact the repository

Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux
RUN yum update -y
```

running: sudo docker build .

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM amazonlinux
---> df7d0b6ddeee
Step 2/2 : RUN yum update -y
---> Running in 14e4e4bad5b1
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
```

result, several https tried and in the end:

```
...URLError: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 5516 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror...
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

if I were you I would check the following things:

- Try Centos7 image and run the same commands
- Try to run `yum clean all` before running update so it should look like this `RUN yum clean all && yum update -y`
- Check the network limitation in DNS resolving and you can check this [link](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) for guide and also this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) from docker to configure custom network
- Also check the firewall configuration on the Host machine

Comment: yum clean all save my day!

Comment: The DNS guide resolved this issue for me. added the docker ip to daemon.json

Answer (score 1):

try using host network if container is having issues with DNS e.g.

`docker build .... --network host ....`

Comment: Not sure whether this work in docker compose as well

Comment: its build arg, if compose file is version 3.4. docker-compose I guess v1.x.x. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074457/how-to-specify-docker-build-network-host-mode-in-docker-compose-at-the-time